# Python removing items in list using reverse iterator

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and currently learning the basics. 
I want to remove duplicates in a list. 
Here is my code:

```
numbers = [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 4, 0, 8, 2, 4]
for item in reversed(numbers):
    if numbers.count(item) > 1:
        numbers.remove(item)
print(numbers)
```

The result I expected is

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 0, 8]
```

However, I got instead

```
[5, 6, 9, 0, 8, 2, 4]
```

I don't know why this happened since I use reversed iterator.
So any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: ```.remove(item)``` is being called on the first instance of each number of the list, not the last one

Comment: While your mistake is new, the correct solution to this sort of issue is already found on [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/364696).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
numbers = [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 4, 0, 8, 2, 4]

finale = list(dict.fromkeys(numbers))
```

**output:**

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 0, 8]
```

> As dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys, the function removes
> any duplicate values from our list. We can then convert our dictionary
> back to a list.

Comment: This is by far the best solution (provided [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/364696)), but it doesn't tell the OP what they did wrong.

Comment: Thank you `ShadowRanger`
.But I usually use this method

Comment: and this is a suggestion and I have explained how it works

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by 7koFnMiP, the **remove()** method removes the *first* occurrence of the element with the specified value.

One way to solve this is to use **pop()** instead of **remove()**, to have a way to reference the index of the object to be removed from the list.

Here's an example, using an iterator referencing the index backwards to start removing from the end of the list:

```
numbers = [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 4, 0, 8, 2, 4]

for item in reversed(numbers):
    if numbers.count(item) > 1:
        # where the difference is:
        numbers.pop(next(i for i in reversed((range(len(numbers)))) if numbers[i] == item))
print(numbers)
```

The output is as expected:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 0, 8]
```

[More info on the built-in function next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

[More info on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Thanks, I thought remove() method removes current element.